Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 24 cannot be smaller than version 28 declared in library [com.android.car.ui:car-ui-lib:2.6.0]
This all happened because I was trying to add a toolbar to the home screen and a slightly different widget to the login screen, although I backed out and the problem still persists.
What makes matters worse is that my application is based on the Arabic language, which forces me to add features that ignite elements and buttons in their specific place despite the device’s language changing or being different.
I always do not get the result I want, as shown in these pictures. I often face problems with the tools.
I always do not get the result I want, as shown in these pictures. I often encounter problems with the tool, either it appears differently than what is required or it distorts the vision (Layout).
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/wemedia_beta_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/wemedia_beta_icon_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.WeMediaBeta"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>

This is the expected result but the application was not built :

